# impossible to display image from strapi with graphQL

Tags: amazon-s3, graphql, strapi

I did a projet with gatsby and strapi.
I upload my image on aws s3 because strapi is deployed on Heroku.

Since then it's impossible to display image i upload in strapi into my page

I had Sharp image but it didn't work and I erased to just add url.
now the page is displaying but no image

here is my graphql :

export const query = graphql`
  query ArticleTemplate($id: String!) {
    strapiArticles(id: {eq: $id}) {
      title
      content
      deuxiemeContenu
      imageContent {
        url
        }
      image {
        url
        }
      author {
        id
        username
      }
    }
  }

Comment: Hi @Reevan, out of curiosity how do you have permissions on your s3 bucket setup?

Comment: @ShawnMatthews i have the permission yes, because i had the error first.
It's more like my query in graphQL couldn't retrieve the image.

Maybe it's someghint to change in gastby-config with the right path or something but for now the image is not displaying.

Comment: is your console log returning anything? What does the src of the image show?

Comment: my console is saying : Cannot query field "childImageSharp" on type "StrapiArticlesImage"

the src is fluid={document.node.image.childImageSharp.fluid}

before (when i was using the sql-lite of strapi) i had no problem with it

Comment: Have you made sure you can run that query form Graphiql?  If so what does it return? Sorry for all the questions just trying to help you trouble shoot.